# Gamepad R2 button number for input manager

Tags: unity, input, joystick, gamepad

This should hopefully be an easy one but i'm stuck on this. I need to stop character movement and camera look if the R2 button on a gamepad is held down.

The gamepad i'm using is a third-party generic usb gamepad and can't find out anywhere which joystick button R2 (right shoulder button) is to enter in the input manager.

Below is the code i'm using for the character move which looks like it should work, its just getting the right button in the input manager - i've tried 0-15 but nothing.

Is there a way to find out the button number or is there a better method for doing what i need?

Thanks,

Paul..

The input was set up by duplicating a Fire button input and changing it's name to DoorTrigger (gravity, deadzone and sensitivity are as they were for the fire button, so 1000, 0.0001 and 1000 respectively) and have been testing the positive button with different button numbers.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public Read_move ReadMove;
    bool TriggerBt = Input.GetButtonDown ("DoorTrigger");

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        GameObject Mover = GameObject.Find ("PlayerA");
        ReadMove = Mover.GetComponent<Read_move> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!TriggerBt) {
            ReadMove.mUP = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");// * speed;
            ReadMove.mLEFT = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");// * speed;
            float translation = ReadMove.mUP * speed;
            float straffe = ReadMove.mLEFT * speed;

            translation *= Time.deltaTime;
            straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

            transform.Translate (straffe, 0, translation);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("escape"))
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need proper gamepad support in Unity, I strongly recommend looking at the paid gamepad libraries in the store.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah i'll have a look at those. Trouble is that this is for a university degree so no budget. I've tried a free one from the store but i can't create a folder outside of my assets folder for some reason. It will create one wthin it but not outside of it.

Comment: Try this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKey.html not sure if it'll work for a controller but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Unity treats the L2 and R2 buttons as an *axis* rather than a button.

From [the answer on this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/960702/how-to-get-input-of-ps3-controllers-r2-or-l2-butto.html):

Create an input named "R2" set the gravity to 1.5, dead zone to 0.3, and the sensivity to 1.1, then use "Joystick Axis" for the type and have it use "10th Axis (Joystick)" for the Axis.

And that should work using `Input.GetButton("R2")`

Or you can set up the existing button you have to use those values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but still not doing anything. Would Unity still treat R2 as an axis if on my gamepad the button is just a button? Unlike the PS4 pad that has a range of values, my gamepad's R2 is just on / off..

Comment: Its possible.  If Axis 9/10 don't work, try the others as well. I'll admit it's unlikely, but that's what I found. If that *still* doesn't work, you might have to get a keybind plugin (like [ReWired](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21676), which is admittedly a good asset for *other* reasons as well) in order to bind it: it might have something really funky.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies. Well, I sussed it. It was Joystick Button 7 and i simply used this if statement and the input manager set up as below:

```
if (!Input.GetButton ("DoorTrigger")) {

}
```

**Input Manager:**
Name: DoorTrigger.
Positive: joystick button 7.
Gravity: 1.5
DeadZone: 0.3
Sensitivity: 1.1
Type: Key or Mouse Button.

Thanks,

Paul..